# how to publish mvc 5 project in vs2017 to local iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, publish, application-pool

I want to publish a MVC5 project to local IIS, I need to correct set connection string, Permissions and application pool in IIS and every things that help me to do it.

When I publish, I see this error.

> **Cannot open database "MyProjectDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-1O5A46C$'.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.
Create a text file (a.txt) in my pc desktop and chenge to (a.udl).
open (a.udl) and set Connection

and test connection
if success then close udl window.
then open with note pad (a.udl) and copy

Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=False; Initial
 Catalog=MyProjectDB; Data Source=.

and Replace to default connection string in Connection String to your Website in IIS.